# How do I compare object variable to a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a string that comes from a form to find a object in a db with the same name of a variable. 
Let's say I want to find a bus station with name "Central" in a db full of bus stations. And if I found one, I want to get the address variable from the "Central" station into a session (for further use). The db is running fine and I can retrieve other stuff from it, but the problem is comparing the two strings.

```
Session["searchFor"]="Central";
Session["adress"]=null;
var db = new Models.DB();

List<Models.Station> allStations = db.Station.ToList();
foreach (Station station in allStations)
{
    if(String.Compare(Session["searchFor"].toString(), station.name) == 0)
    {
        Session["adress"]=station.adress;
        break;
    } 
}
```

I have tried every possible compare to method I have found online, but nothing seems to be working.

My DB class looks like this:

```
public class Station
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string adress { get; set; }
    }
```

The page that write it out looks like this.

```
From station: @Session["searchFor"] <br />
From station adress: @Session["adress"] <br />
```

And the result,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL2BU.png)
 the session has not been given a value by the function. I don't know if it's the compare function that does not work, or the line that are supposed to be given the session the value. If I write

```
if(String.Compare(Session["searchFor"].toString(), station.name) == 0)
        {
            Session["adress"]="TEST";
            break;
        }
```

it does NOT says "From station adress: Test" on the website  either.

Comment: What is the 'problem' here? What happens when you run this code?

Comment: C# is case sensitive, and `toString` is not a valid method of `object`. [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_ToString) would be, but apparently you want `if ((string)Session["searchFor"] == station.name)`.

Comment: @Sach The problem is that I get nothing. The compare function does not work and the session is empty.

Comment: Also, your `adress` spelling is wrong. Are you sure that's what you have in the database as well?

Comment: A side note: instead of grabbing all stations and looping them, why not use a `where` on that list to *only* get what you need; then you can get rid of that other code.

Comment: You'll [have to debug your code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Since what you posted won't compile we can't do that for you.

Comment: @Sach I had to translate the variables because I don't write it in english. But I have checked over 100 times that it is the same variables everywhere.

Comment: Also I the db is running locally on Visual Studio and I am using MVC. I have tried all your solutions, but no one seems to be working.

Comment: I don't think you've tried all solutions. Have you tried debugging as @DourHighArch suggested? You should step through each line of code and see what happens.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That would be, again, fetching the entire table and filtering on the client. To pass it to the DB, the `Where` must be before the `ToList`.

Comment: @GSerg haha, yeah, my bad; good catch.

Comment: @GSerg I added some extra code and description to the question, if that may help to see whats wrong.

Comment: @revl I am sorry to say you really are missing some of the basic understanding of each line of code you are writing, the code snippet you have shared under the UPDATE of your question is alarmingly demonstrative of this. You ae actually iterating over all Stations twice for no reason O(n2). I think the answers you need are bigger than a single question on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

There is alot of improvements you can make with this code. First off, `Session["searchFor"].ToString()` is really [Object.toString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) and it is not doing what you think it is doing, it is not converting the value for the "searchFor" key to a string.

Below is a much improved version that is just common best practices in any coding language and also a couple common patterns in C#. It includes correctly spelling variables and also upper casing Properties in C# classes and dealing with potential case sensitivity of your string comparisons.

```
Session["searchFor"] = "Central";  //setting Session values for testing
//Session["address"] = null; there is no need for this.
var db = new Models.DB();

List<Models.Station> allStations = db.Station.ToList();
var searchForValue = (string) Session["searchFor"];
foreach (Station station in allStations)
{
    if (searchForValue.ToLower() == station.Name.ToLower())
    {
        Session["address"] = station.Address;
        break;
    }
}
```

And here is a version that is very common in C# using LINQ:

```
//setting Session values for testing
Session["searchFor"] = "Central";
var db = new Models.DB();

List<Models.Station> allStations = db.Station.ToList();
var searchForValue = (string) Session["searchFor"];
var station = allStations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == searchForValue.ToLower());
if (station != null)
{
    Session["address"] = station.Address;
}
```

Comment: @revl yes you are doing a poor job of explaining what your issue is and what is not working